# Exporting an animation as a gif file

Tags: export, animation, gif-format

So, I have the code

```
Export["vectors.gif",
  Animate[
   Graphics[
     {White,Arrow[{{0, 0}, {a,b}}]}, 
     GridLines->Automatic,Axes->True,Background->Black, 
     PlotRange->5], 
  {a, -2, 2,0.25},{b,-2,2,0.25}, AnimationRepetitions->1]]
```

but it just exported an image of an instant of the animation. How do I export the full animation?

**EDIT**: Okay, new problem. Using the code

```
Export["vectors.gif", 
Table[Graphics[{White, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {a, b}}]}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, Axes -> True, Background -> Black, 
PlotRange -> 5], {a, -2, 2, 0.25}, {b, -2, 2, 0.25}]]
```

exports an animation, but it looks kind of strange. It gives a bunch of smaller images it animates - like it is taking each value of one variable and animating the second variable across it, if that makes sense. It doesn't give one coherent image.

Thanks!

Comment: But, an animation is supposed to be a flat list of images; why are you feeding a matrix of images to the exporter?

Comment: Export this instead: `Table[Graphics[{White, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {a, a}}]}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, Axes -> True, Background -> Black, 
  PlotRange -> 5], {a, -2, 2, 0.25}]`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thank you! Now it gives a single coherent image. Strangely enough, though, the arrow isn't rotating around the origin like I thought it would; just going diagonally in a straight line and flipping directions. Not sure why.

Comment: Try `Table[Graphics[{White, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {2 Cos[c], 2 Sin[c]}}]}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, Axes -> True, Background -> Black, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {c, -3 Pi/4, Pi/4, Pi/8}]`

Comment: @bbgodfrey, that gives just the image again when exported, like my original code.

Comment: Yes, I copied the wrong line of code.  See my edited comment.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, yes, this works perfectly, thank you! If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the following to obtain the desired file

```
Table[Graphics[{White, Arrow[{{0, 0}, 2 Sqrt[2] {Cos[c], Sin[c]}}]}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, Axes -> True, Background -> Black, 
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {c, -3 Pi/4, Pi/4, Pi/8}]
```

Answer (score 9):

You should export just the `List`, not the object created by `Animate`. For this, `Table` is a good idea.

```
Export["vectors.gif", 
Table[Graphics[{White, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {a, b}}]}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, Axes -> True, Background -> Black, 
PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {a, -2, 2, 0.25}, {b, -2, 2, 0.25}]]
```

On the other hand: You seem to have two animation variables. What is the meaning of this? Should they be varying simultaneously? If so, just get rid of `b` and change the `Arrow` to point to `{a,a}`. If not, could you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - yes, it can just be `{a,a}`.

Comment: Okay, this works, but a little oddly. After looking at the result, it gives a bunch of smaller images it animates - like it is taking each value of one variable and animating the second variable across it, if that makes sense. It doesn't give one coherent image.

Comment: Yes, because you're animating over two variables as it stands. Time only has one direction, after all, so the animation is making one frame for each `a` value and then animating them all through the `b` values (or vice versa). There is no way to have it animate two variables *independently*; the only actual parameter in a gif is the frame number.